# Pig Conditional Operators

Tags: apache-pig

Consider the below relation

```
test = LOAD 'input' USING PigStorage(',') as (a:chararray, b:chararray);
```

Is there a way to achieve the following

```
if (b == 1) {
    a = 'abc';
else if (b == 2) {
    a = 'xyz';
else 
    // retain whatever is there in the column 'a'
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do a `FOREACH` and use the ternary operator as follows.

```
test2 = FOREACH test GENERATE (b=='1' ? 'abc' : (b=='2' ? 'xyz' : a)) AS a, b;
```