# Using conditionals in Pig

Tags: hadoop, if-statement, apache-pig, conditional-statements

I want to simulate an if-then-else block in a pig script.

PseudoCode :

```
if(flag=set) then STORE INTO '<path>' USING <StorageUDF()> else do nothing
```

Is there a way I can use the SPLIT command?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pig Conditional Operators](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16975210/pig-conditional-operators)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17669522/is-there-any-conditional-if-like-operator-in-apache-pig, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16975210/pig-conditional-operators, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18913764/pig-split-lack-of-default-or-if-else

Comment: No it's not. My question is around being able to put a conditional on executing an entire statement and not setting variables