# If else condition in Pig to name output file

Tags: if-statement, hdfs, apache-pig

I am using pig to parse a file, I want to apply **if-else** condition to check if a statement is present or not. If the statemnet is not there i make the output file name as `No` otherwise i keep the output file name as it is of the statement. How can i do that.

Example:

```
amit|COD|12543|nagpur|MH|India
```

Now i want to check if my `$1` is empty or not if it is empty i want to make my output file name to be **`N.txt`** or **`COD.txt`**(In this case $1 is COD it may be different in other situations, i want $1 value to be output name).

I checked and found that pig has conditional operator but no If-else can anyone please suggest some work around over here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bincond operator/ Ternary Opertor ( ?:) should help.

```
output = FOREACH input_data GENERATE $0, ($1 IS NULL ? 'N.txt' : $1) AS output_file_name, $2..;
```

Refer [Pig Conditional Operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16975210/pig-conditional-operators) for an example.